# Sketch the level curves of the function

Tags: multivariable-calculus, graphing-functions

$f(x,y)= (y-3x)^2$

let $k=0$

then $z=(y-3x)^2 \to 0=y^2-6xy+9x^2$

This is as far as I can get is my approach incorrect? Is this a special case of a polynomial degree two?

maybe $0=y^2-6xy+9x^2-z$

Comment: It is not necessary to square the expression for $k=0$ because $(y-3x)^2=0$ if and only if $y-3x=0$.

Comment: what about for k=1?

Comment: For $k\ne0$ you will have to square both sides and solve the resulting quadratic equation for $y$ in terms of $x$. I would recommend setting it to $k$ in general then square the left side and solve using the quadratic formula. It will simplify nicely and you will get a general solution for the level curves that works for any positive value of $k$.

Comment: $z = (y-3x)^2 \implies \sqrt z = y-3x$  Now set $z$ equal to $1,2,3,\cdots$

Comment: Your approach is correct but inefficient as it hides the simplicity of the solution. The function is factored, keep it factored.

Answer (score 1):

The way I would do it would be to break up the level curves into a "top" and "bottom" half:

$$(y-3x)^2 = k  \text{ (constant) }\implies \begin{cases} y - 3x = +\sqrt{k} \\ y- 3x = -\sqrt{k} \end{cases}$$

It will be nicer to compute if you pick your  $k$'s to be perfect squares.